# How would I be able to multiple select and pass data in the given format in vue js html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

I need to pass the data in the given format.

```
rules : [{
        name:null,
        section:null,
        data   : [{head:null,value:null}]
    }],
```

This is the problem I am facing. Hope somebody could help me sort out a solution. The snippet is given. I need to pass data in the format given above. If another array is needed inside rules[], it is also fine

Is another array needed for head and value inside data[]. This will be also fine, if needed. Hoping for a help. Please help me to have a solution.

Please change the select to read the issues

```js
    addForm = new Vue({
      el: "#addForm",
      data: {
        rules: [{
          name: null,
          section: null,
          data: [{
            head: null,
            value: null
          }]
        }],

      },
      methods: {
        addNewRules: function() {
          this.rules.push({
            name: null,
            section: null,
            data: [{
              head: null,
              value: null
            }]
          });
        },
      }
    })
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>
   

        <div id="addForm">
      
    
    <div class="card-content" v-for="(bok, index) in rules" :key="index">
         <p>This is the first part which is fine for me</p>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group label-floating">
                  <label class="control-label">Act</label>
                  <select class="form-control" v-model="bok.name">
                    <option value="Act,1972">Act,1972</option>
                    <option value="Rule,2012">Rule,2012(CEMR)</option>
                    <option value="Act,1961">Act,1961</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="form-group label-floating">
                <label class="control-label">Section</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="bok.section">
              </div>
            </div>
    
       
        
    
    <div class="row" v-if="bok.name == 'Act,1972'">
           <p>When selecting Act,1972 is here rules.data.head. Fine for me</p>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group label-floating">
                  <label class="control-label">Arms</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="bok.data[0].head" required="">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
    
        
            <div class="row" v-if="bok.name == 'Rule,2012'">
<p>When Selecting Rule,2012 HOW TO PASS values rules.data.head in this case . There are two input fields here???</p>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group label-floating">
                  <label class="control-label">Item</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="bok.data[0].head" required="">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group label-floating">
                  <label class="control-label">Quantity Seized</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="bok.data[0].head" required="">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
    
       
            <div class="row" v-if="bok.name == 'Act,1961'">
 <p>When selecting Act,1931 Its a select option, I need to select multiple options from here and pass values as rules.data.head. //After I select multiple options I have input fields corresponding to the options. This to be send as rules.data.value.. How
            to do this?</p>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group label-floating">
                  <label class="control-label">Select</label>
                  <select class=" form-control" v-model="bok.data[0].head" multiple="">
                    <option value="1">life</option>
                    <option value="2">Enment</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
       
            <div class="row" v-if="bok.data[0].head == 1">
 <p>If option is 1, i should display this and pass value as rules.data.value . HERE THERE ARE TWO INPUT FIELDS How to pass the values</p>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group label-floating">
                  <label class="control-label">Area1</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" required="" v-model="bok.data[0].value">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group label-floating">
                  <label class="control-label">Area2</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" required="" v-model="bok.data[0].value">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row" v-if="bok.data[0].head == 2">
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group label-floating">
                  <label class="control-label">No.</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" required="" v-model="bok.data[0].value">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group label-floating">
                  <label class="control-label">Model</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" required="">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <a @click="addNewRules">Add Another Rule</a>
        </div>
```

Comment: I created a  [mcve] for you using the `<>` snippet editor

Comment: I think you have to change the format of rules[]

Comment: @mplungjan Sir, can you plx help me to have a solution

Comment: I have no experience with Vue, but your inline comments were hard to read and test. Please change the snippet to show what you want if it does not show it now

Comment: sir i have updated.. pls check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach is basically change the type of the `data[0].head` and `data[0].value` depending on the options you selected.

So for example, if you select `Rule,2012`, then `data[0].head` would be an `object` with `item` and `qty` as its items. And if you select `Act,1961`, `data[0].head` would be an `array` of numbers (e.g. `['1', '2']`) and `data[0].value` would be an `object` with *`area_1` and `area_2`* or *`number` and `model`* *or all the four items*.

*See and try the code snippet to see the code I added/changed.*

(Or compare your code with mine and you'd see the changes.)

```js
addForm = new Vue({
      el: "#addForm",
      data: {
        rules: [{
          name: null,
          section: null,
          data: [{
            head: null,
            value: null
          }]
        }],

      },
      methods: {
        addNewRules: function() {
          this.rules.push({
            name: null,
            section: null,
            data: [{
              head: null,
              value: null
            }]
          });
        },

        removeRuleDataValueProps: function(i) {
          var d = this.rules[i].data[0];

          if (jQuery.inArray('1', d.head) < 0) {
            Vue.delete(d.value, 'area_1');
            Vue.delete(d.value, 'area_2');
          }

          if (jQuery.inArray('2', d.head) < 0) {
            Vue.delete(d.value, 'number');
            Vue.delete(d.value, 'model');
          }
        },

        _setRuleDataHeadDataType: function(i) {
          var d = this.rules[i].data[0],
            h = d.head,
            _h = d._head,
            _restore = true;

          if (undefined === _h) {
            d._head = h;
            _restore = false;
          }

          switch (this.rules[i].name) {
            case 'Rule,2012':
              var a = Array.isArray(h);
              if (a || null === h || 'object' !== typeof h) {
                Vue.set(d, 'head', {});
              }

              break;

            case 'Act,1961':
              if (!Array.isArray(h)) {
                Vue.set(d, 'head', []);
              }

              break;

            default:
              if (_restore && undefined !== _h) {
                d.head = _h;
              }

              break;
          }
        },

        _setRuleDataValueDataType: function(i) {
          var d = this.rules[i].data[0],
            v = d.value,
            _v = d._value,
            _restore = true;

          if (undefined === _v) {
            d._value = v;
            _restore = false;
          }

          switch (this.rules[i].name) {
            case 'Act,1972':
            case 'Act,1961':
              var a = Array.isArray(v);
              if (a || null === v || 'object' !== typeof v) {
                Vue.set(d, 'value', {});
              }

              if (_restore) {
                this.removeRuleDataValueProps(i);
              }

              break;

            default:
              if (_restore && undefined !== _v) {
                d.value = _v;
              }

              break;
          }
        },

        setRuleDataType: function(i, k) {
          if (this.rules[i] && this.rules[i].data[0]) {
            if (!k || 'head' === k) {
              this._setRuleDataHeadDataType(i);
            }

            if (!k || 'value' === k) {
              this._setRuleDataValueDataType(i);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>
   

        <div id="addForm">
      
    <h3>Try the different options and see the JSON output changes.</h3>
    <div class="card-content" v-for="(bok, index) in rules" :key="index">
         <p>This is the first part which is fine for me</p>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group label-floating">
                  <label class="control-label">Act</label>
                  <!-- Here we change the type of `bok.data[0].head` depending on the selected option. -->
                  <select class="form-control" v-model="bok.name" @change="setRuleDataType(index)">
                    <option value="Act,1972">Act,1972</option>
                    <option value="Rule,2012">Rule,2012(CEMR)</option>
                    <option value="Act,1961">Act,1961</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>
            <!--</div>-->
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="form-group label-floating">
                <label class="control-label">Section</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="bok.section">
              </div>
            </div>
    
       
        
    <!-- Here, `bok.data[0].head` is expected to be a `string`. -->
    <div class="row" v-if="bok.name == 'Act,1972'">
           <p>When selecting Act,1972 is here rules.data.head. Fine for me</p>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group label-floating">
                  <label class="control-label">Arms</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="bok.data[0].head" @change="setRuleDataType(index, 'value')" required="">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
    
            <!-- Here, `bok.data[0].head` is an `object` with 'item' and 'qty'. -->
            <div class="row" v-if="bok.name == 'Rule,2012'">
<p>When Selecting Rule,2012 HOW TO PASS values rules.data.head in this case . There are two input fields here???</p>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group label-floating">
                  <label class="control-label">Item</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="bok.data[0].head.item" required="">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group label-floating">
                  <label class="control-label">Quantity Seized</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="bok.data[0].head.qty" required="">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
    
            <!-- Here, `bok.data[0].head` would be an array of numbers. -->
            <div class="row" v-if="bok.name == 'Act,1961'">
 <p>When selecting Act,1931 Its a select option, I need to select multiple options from here and pass values as rules.data.head. //After I select multiple options I have input fields corresponding to the options. This to be send as rules.data.value.. How
            to do this?</p>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group label-floating">
                  <label class="control-label">Select</label>
                  <select class=" form-control" v-model="bok.data[0].head" @change="removeRuleDataValueProps(index)" multiple="">
                    <option value="1">life</option>
                    <option value="2">Enment</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
       
            <div class="row" v-if="jQuery.inArray('1', bok.data[0].head) > -1">
 <p>If option is 1, i should display this and pass value as rules.data.value . HERE THERE ARE TWO INPUT FIELDS How to pass the values</p>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group label-floating">
                  <label class="control-label">Area1</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" required="" v-model="bok.data[0].value.area_1">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group label-floating">
                  <label class="control-label">Area2</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" required="" v-model="bok.data[0].value.area_2">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row" v-if="jQuery.inArray('2', bok.data[0].head) > -1">
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group label-floating">
                  <label class="control-label">No.</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" required="" v-model="bok.data[0].value.number">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group label-floating">
                  <label class="control-label">Model</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" required="" v-model="bok.data[0].value.model">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <h3>The JSON value of <code>bok</code></h3>
            <textarea rows="3" cols="75%" readonly>{{ JSON.stringify(bok) }}</textarea>
          </div>
          <a @click="addNewRules">Add Another Rule</a>
        </div>
```

Comment: Sir, v-if="jQuery.inArray('1', bok.data[0].head) > -1" it is saying not defined.. any other method for this

Comment: vue.js:435 [Vue warn]: Property or method "jQuery" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the data option.

(found in <Root>)

Comment: [Vue warn]: Error in render function: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'inArray' of undefined"

(found in <Root>)

Comment: vue.js:522 TypeError: Cannot read property 'inArray' of undefined
    at eval (eval at makeFunction (vue.js:9252), <anonymous>:3:12023)
    at Proxy.renderList (vue.js:3640)
    at Proxy.eval (eval at makeFunction (vue.js:9252), <anonymous>:3:6592)
    at Vue$3.Vue._render (vue.js:3866)
    at Vue$3.updateComponent (vue.js:2413)
    at Watcher.get (vue.js:2750)
    at new Watcher (vue.js:2733)
    at mountComponent (vue.js:2417)
    at Vue$3.$mount (vue.js:7512)

Comment: Did you try the code snippet? It worked fine for me. And if you compared my code with your original code, I loaded jQuery on the page. See the HTML panel of the code snippet editor. `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` (but it doesn't have to be version `2.1.1`)

Comment: i am using jquery-3.2.1.min.js

Comment: AS soon as I write v-if="jQuery.inArray('1', bok.data[0].head) > -1" i am getting the above error

Comment: I'm not getting that error? And I've actually tested the code with jQuery version 3.3.1 and 1.12.4, and both worked fine. Try editing the code snippet and change the `2.1.1` to `3.2.1` and it should still work fine. So can you paste your code (or the code you attempted) on Pastebin and share its link here?

Comment: Alternatively, add a new method to the `methods` options of the Vue instance (i.e. `addForm`): `inArray: function( value, arr ) { return jQuery.inArray( value, arr ); }` and replace `v-if="jQuery.inArray('1', bok.data[0].head) > -1"` with `v-if="inArray('1', bok.data[0].head) > -1"`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171480/discussion-between-sally-cj-and-wanderer).

Comment: hello sir, can you please help me with a problem

Comment: I posted a reply there.

Answer (score 1):

**My opinion,**

1. Based on the HTML you provied, create one data property=ruleTemplate (it makes sure v-model with related form controls).
2. When add new rules, push one clone of the template to the rules
3. When you need the data, just convert the rules to the specific format like 
   `this.getFormattedRules` in below demo.

**Below is the demo:**

```js
addForm = new Vue({
      el: "#addForm",
      data: {
        ruleTemplates: {
          name: '',
          section: '',
          subMenu: {
          'Act,1972': '',
          'Rule,2012': {'item': '','qty': ''},
          'Act,1961': {'head':[], options:{'option1':'', 'option2':''}}
          }
        },
        rules: [{
            name: '',
            section: '',
            subMenu: {
            'Act,1972': '',
            'Rule,2012': {'item': '','qty': ''},
            'Act,1961': {'head':[], options:{'option1':'', 'option2':''}}
            }
          }
        ],
      },
      computed: {
        formatedJson: function () {
          let handler1972 = function (data) {
            return [{'head': 'Arms', 'value': data}]
          }
          let handler2012 = function (data) {
            return [{'head': 'item', 'value': data.item},{'head': 'qty', 'value': data.qty}]
          }
          let handler1961 = function (data) {
            return [{'head': 'option1', 'value': data.options.option1},{'head': 'option1', 'value': data.options.option2}]
          }
          let handlers = {'Act,1972': handler1972, 'Rule,2012': handler2012, 'Act,1961': handler1961
          }
          return this.rules.map((rule) => {
            let formatedRule = new Object()
            // convert the rule to the specific format
            formatedRule.name = rule.name
            formatedRule.section = rule.section
            handler = handlers[rule.name]
            formatedRule.data = handler ? handler(rule.subMenu[rule.name]) : []
            return formatedRule
          })
        }
      },
      methods: {
        addNewRules: function() {
          this.rules.push(Object.assign({},this.ruleTemplates))
        }
      }
    })
```

```css
.show-format {
  position:absolute;
  top:2px;
  right -4px;
  background-color:gray
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>
   
   <div id="addForm">
    <div class="show-format">Format: {{formatedJson}}</div>
    <div class="card-content" v-for="(bok, index) in rules" :key="index">
         <p>This is the first part which is fine for me</p>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group label-floating">
                  <label class="control-label">Act</label>
                  <select class="form-control" v-model="bok.name">
                    <option value="Act,1972">Act,1972</option>
                    <option value="Rule,2012">Rule,2012(CEMR)</option>
                    <option value="Act,1961">Act,1961</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="form-group label-floating">
                <label class="control-label">Section</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="bok.section">
              </div>
            </div>
    
       
        
    
    <div class="row" v-if="bok.name == 'Act,1972'">
           <p>When selecting Act,1972 is here rules.data.head. Fine for me</p>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group label-floating">
                  <label class="control-label">Arms</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="bok.subMenu['Act,1972']" required="">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
    
        
            <div class="row" v-if="bok.name == 'Rule,2012'">
<p>When Selecting Rule,2012 HOW TO PASS values rules.data.head in this case . There are two input fields here???</p>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group label-floating">
                  <label class="control-label">Item</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="bok.subMenu['Rule,2012']['item']" required="">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group label-floating">
                  <label class="control-label">Quantity Seized</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="bok.subMenu['Rule,2012']['qty']" required="">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
    
       
            <div class="row" v-if="bok.name == 'Act,1961'">
 <p>When selecting Act,1931 Its a select option, I need to select multiple options from here and pass values as rules.data.head. //After I select multiple options I have input fields corresponding to the options. This to be send as rules.data.value.. How
            to do this?</p>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group label-floating">
                  <label class="control-label">Select</label>
                  <select class=" form-control" v-model="bok.subMenu['Act,1961'].head" >
                    <option value="1">life</option>
                    <option value="2">Enment</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
       
            <div class="row" v-if="bok.subMenu['Act,1961'].head == 1">
 <p>If option is 1, i should display this and pass value as rules.data.value . HERE THERE ARE TWO INPUT FIELDS How to pass the values</p>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group label-floating">
                  <label class="control-label">Area1</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" required="" v-model="bok.subMenu['Act,1961'].options.option1">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group label-floating">
                  <label class="control-label">Area2</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" required="" v-model="bok.subMenu['Act,1961'].options.option2">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row" v-if="bok.subMenu['Act,1961'].head == 2">
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group label-floating">
                  <label class="control-label">No.</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" required="" v-model="bok.subMenu['Act,1961'].options.option1">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group label-floating">
                  <label class="control-label">Model</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" required="" v-model="bok.subMenu['Act,1961'].options.option2">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <a @click="addNewRules" style="background-color:green">Add Another Rule</a>
        </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

hey why don't you go with multi-select checkbox drop-down and apply v-model on checkbox. ? 
Link: [How to use Checkbox inside Select Option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17714705/how-to-use-checkbox-inside-select-option#answers)